# Java unchecked warnings add arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, warnings, unchecked

Here is the main program

```
public class MainPerson {

public MainPerson(){}

public static void StartMainPerson()
{
    int i = 1;
    ArrayList<SortedPair> PersonList;
    ArrayList<Person> InitializedPersonList;        
    final int NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE = 6;

    PersonList = new ArrayList<>();
    InitializedPersonList = new ArrayList<>();

    InitializedPersonList.add(new Person( "Assaf Malki" , 1984));
    InitializedPersonList.add(new Person( "Assaf Malki" , 1984));
    InitializedPersonList.add(new Person( "Breanna Romberger" , 1920));
    InitializedPersonList.add(new Person( "Latrice Lane" , 1930));
    InitializedPersonList.add(new Person( "Bridgett Couch" , 1940));
    InitializedPersonList.add(new Person( "Roxane Sova" , 1950));
    InitializedPersonList.add(new Person( "Donnette Weston" , 1960));
    InitializedPersonList.add(new Person( "Milton Kopecky" , 1970));
    InitializedPersonList.add(new Person( "Rosella Vandoren" , 1980));
    InitializedPersonList.add(new Person( "Kayleigh Willimas" , 1990));
    InitializedPersonList.add(new Person( "Zula Lashua" , 2000));
    InitializedPersonList.add(new Person( "Ralph Baudoin" , 2010));
    InitializedPersonList.add(new Person( "Kenton Tseng" , 2005));
    InitializedPersonList.add(new Person( "Brendon Gilchrest" , 1995));

    Iterator itr = InitializedPersonList.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.print("Pair " + i + " is " + itr.next() + " and " + itr.next() + ".\n");
        i = i + 1;
    }

    i = 0;
    System.out.print("\n");
    Iterator itr1 = InitializedPersonList.iterator();

    while(i < NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE)
    {

        try{
            System.out.println("Adding pair number " + (i+1) + "..");
            PersonList.add(new SortedPair((Person) itr1.next(), (Person) itr1.next()));
        }
        catch (IllegalPair e)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid input, same person name, try again.");
            continue;
        }

        i = i + 1;

    }

    System.out.println("");

    for (SortedPair Value : PersonList)
    {
        System.out.println(Value);
    }
}

}
```

Here is SortedPair

```
public class SortedPair <E extends Comparable<E>>
{
    E Max_Element;
    E Min_Element;

    public SortedPair(E FirstElement, E SecondElemnt) throws IllegalPair
    {
        int Compare_Result = FirstElement.compareTo(SecondElemnt);

        if (Compare_Result == 0)
        {
            Max_Element = null;
            Min_Element = null;
            throw new IllegalPair(FirstElement.toString(), SecondElemnt.toString());
        }
        else if (Compare_Result > 0)
        {
            Max_Element = FirstElement;
            Min_Element = SecondElemnt;
        }
        else 
        {
            Max_Element = SecondElemnt;
            Min_Element = FirstElement;

        }
    }

    public E getFirst()
    {
        return Max_Element;
    }

    public E getSecond()
    {
        return Min_Element;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%s is bigger then %s.", getFirst(), getSecond());
    }

}
```

I'm getting the following warning

```
MainPerson.java:60: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to SortedPair(E,E) as a member of the raw type SortedPair
                PersonList.add(new SortedPair((Person) itr1.next(), (Person) itr1.next()));
                               ^
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Comparable<E> declared in class SortedPair
```

And I don't understand way.

I tried changing `ArrayList<Person> InitializedPersonList;` to `ArrayList<Comperable> InitializedPersonList;` but it didn't work.

Any idea guys?

I think the question is pretty clear, how much text can I add Common..

Comment: You tried `InitializedPersonList = new ArrayList<>();` to `InitializedPersonList = new ArrayList<Person>();`

Comment: @Evans: That won't change anything.

Comment: You should also be getting a warning about `Iterator`

Comment: Following the Java naming conventions would help make the code more readable...

Comment: Why? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: read and obey this please http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Answer (score 2):

What you need is

```
List<SortedPair<Person>> PersonList = new ArrayList<SortedPair<Person>>();
List<Person> InitializedPersonList = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Comment: Yep. Elaborating on this; your SortedPair class is generic; you need to declare the parametric type (Person)

Comment: I also tried this one. It gives me he following: type argument Person is not within bounds of type-variable E
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Comparable<E> declared in class SortedPair

Comment: You've declared the parametric type of SortedPair as 'extending Comparable'; this is a requirement for the type. Does the type (Person) implement Comparable?

Comment: @user2102697 that means your `Person` class has to implement `Comparable<Person>`

Comment: It does public class Person implements Comparable{

Comment: Also tried ArrayList<SortedPair<Comparable>> PersonList; and ArrayList<SortedPair<Comparable<Person>>> PersonList; didnt work.

Comment: @user2102697 make it implement `Comparable<Person>` not just Comparable: `public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {`

Comment: You should implement the interface Comparable in class Person and then declare the Arraylist as ArrayList<SortedPair<Person>>. Look in google for "implement Comparable".

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean public class Person implements Comparable<Person>? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, since you use Person as constructor arguments to create the Object SortedPair.

Answer (score 0):

Please use correct Java formating. Variable are never started with capitals. This makes it very disturbing to read for other java devs.

BTW: I think Marco is right.

Comment: As a side note, you should've added this as a comment, not an answer, because you are not answering the OP's question, but giving remarks... No offense ))